# How to integrate Zend_XmlRpc module into Symfony2.1 application?

Tags: php, symfony, dependencies, zend-framework2, xml-rpc

I need to install `Zend_XmlRpc` module into my Symfony 2.1 application.

I tried the obvious way using `composer.json` dependencies:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "zendframework/zend-xmlrpc": "dev-master"
},
```

I got the following problems:

```
- Installation request for zendframework/zend-xmlrpc dev-master -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-xmlrpc dev-master.
- zendframework/zend-xmlrpc dev-master requires zendframework/zend-http dev-master -> no matching package found.
```

I'have added the package requirements from the https://packagist.org/packages/zendframework/zend-xmlrpc

```
    "zendframework/zend-http": "dev-master",
    "zendframework/zend-math": "dev-master",
    "zendframework/zend-server": "dev-master",
    "zendframework/zend-stdlib": "dev-master",
    "zendframework/zend-xmlrpc": "dev-master"
```

But now I've got more problems as each of this package has it's own requirements.

My issue is that I have browsed all these requirements and in the end I am ending with installing the "whole" framework.

I get the `http` package, the `loader` package,  `event manager`, which I am pretty sure symfony already got them.

Isn't there a way to integrate only the XMLRPC package and maybe bridge the functioanlity with the already existing one from Symfony components?

And if there isn't any solution, how can I force composer to auto install recursively all the required dependencies, as there are many of them, and is weird work to add them manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any reason for use the unstable version of the package.

Instead add

```
"require": {
    ...
    "zendframework/zend-xmlrpc": "2.1.*"
},
```

Comment: accepted, even if it installs all the zendframework, I assume that the autoload whould take care of not loading allexisting classes on my hard-drive :). thank you

Comment: How to register in the appKernal.php

Comment: @Sanjith Only bundles can be registered in SF AppKernel. This is a library which you must implement in your own bundle